# fancyhdr package on \part not appearing

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm currently trying to set header and footer using `fancydhr`, everything works exepct on a `\part` page, see screenchot, header and footer not showing up

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%       ---haut de page------
\fancyhead[L]{Pierre LE GUEN}          %Entête Gauche
\fancyhead[C]{Tex}             %Entête Centre
\fancyhead[R]{stackexchange.com}                          %Entête Droite
%       ---bas de page------
\fancyfoot[L]{University}                %Bas Gauche
\fancyfoot[C]{Thanks for help}       %Bas Centre
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}  %Bas Droite

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\raggedleft\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\vspace{3pt}\MakeUppercase{\partname} \thepart}
{0pt}
{\vspace{1pc}\huge}
%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
%

\begin{document}
\part{MWE for tex}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

From :
[image: From]

To: `\part` with header and footer present (see code)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\assignpagestyle{\part}{fancy}
```

after `titleformat{\part}...`